# positioning jQuery qTip inside jqueryUI-Draggable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-draggable, qtip

I have a problem in jqueryUI draggable Bootstrap modal with qTip form validator in an Asp.Net web application. As the requirement, I have made the bootstrap modal draggable using jqueryUI Draggable. The problem is, if the tooltip is active and we have dragged the bootstrap modal, the qtip will not move with the modal as displayed in the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTWLy.jpg) . I am using the following qTip settings:

```
var q = $(inputs).qtip({
    position: {
        my: 'center left',
        at: 'center right'
    },
    content: {
        text: function (api) {
            return getValidator.call(this).html();
        }
    },
    show: {
        ready: true,
        event: 'none'
    },
    hide: {
        event: 'none'
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-red ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded'
    },
    events: {
        show: function (event, api) {
            var $this = api.elements.target;
            var validator = getValidator.call($this);
            if (validator.length == 0)
                event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

I tried to use `type: 'relative',` and `container: $(this).parent(),` for the position. But the qtip is still not moving.

I am using following to move the bootstrap modal and it is working as expected.

```
    $(".modal").draggable({
            handle: ".modal-header",
            containment: "body"
        });
```

Suggestions/fixes are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wont work because if you take a look closely at the DOM, the actual qtip elements are appended to the body irrespective of the element on which you have initialized it. Hence it is not present in your draggable div and will not be dragged.

My best bet would be to hide the qtip error message when dragging starts and re render them  when the dragging has been stopped.

Comment: Yes mandeep. I agree with your point. But in my case, it is not possible to re-initiate qtip after dragging because me in asp.net and this is a requiredfield validator which is complex to customize.